# TURN server installation on AWS EC2 free-tier instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, webrtc, coturn

I enabled all necessary ports for **coturn** server on my instance from security group. I also configure the turnserver.conf file correctly, but still when I added my turn server on trickleICE, it shows error **701**.

Here is my **turnserver.conf**:

```
listening-port=3478

# and 5349 for TLS (secure)
tls-listening-port=5349
#alt-listening-port=80

# Require authentication
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech


# Specify the server name and the realm that will be used
# if is your first time configuring, just use the domain as name
server-name=mydomain.com
realm=mydomain.com

# Important:
# Create a test user if you want
# You can remove this user after testing
user=<myusername>:<mypassword>

#min-port=705
#max-port=1000

total-quota=100
stale-nonce=600

external-ip=<my public ip>/<my private ip>
listening-ip=<my private ip>
relay-ip=<my public ip>
```

Screenshot of ec2 inbound security group:
[security-groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hedFE.png)

Screenshot of:
[TRICLE ICE RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqO4U.png)

Can someone help me with this? When I entered the command

```
sudo systemctl status coturn
```

The status is active
[screenshot of coturn status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDVhV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two parts from your config file that needs to be modified.

1. set the `relay-ip` to your private ip address.

```
external-ip=<my public ip>/<my private ip>
listening-ip=<my private ip>
relay-ip=<my private ip>
```

2. In your ec2's security group settings, you have set the inbound rules for IPv6 addresses. You should add `0.0.0.0/0` (for IPv4) to the CIDR blocks field in the inbound rules.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to gather more information on the reasons of the failure.

I'm assuming you're configuring the Trickle ICE application with a `turn:IP:port` server URL, which allows for unencrypted exchanges with TURN.

This means you can trace on your machine, e.g. using Wireshark, and verify whether the STUN binding requests and TURN Allocate requests are being sent out to the expected TURN server's public IP and port, and whether there are responses to them being received by the browser.

Additional checks you can do is on the TURN server side. With something like `netstat -tunapl` you can verify that `coturn` is not only running but also listening on the expected port (which should be 3478 since you left it unspecified).

If all looks as expected, then run a trace on `coturn`'s host while you trigger a "Gather candidates" from the Trickle ICE application. You could use something like `ngrep -d any -lqtW byline port 3478` to see the activity and content exchanged.

If `coturn` doesn't receive anything, then check again the EC2 instance Security Group and ensure you're allowing traffic to port 3478 UDP (and TCP). Double check the EC2 instance's public IP address is what you're using in the Trickle ICE application.

If instead you have more than one network interface assigned to that EC2 instance, then ensure you have a `listening-ip` configuration item set to the correct *private* IP address, and an `external-ip` directive which includes `PUBLIC_IP:PRIVATE_IP`, where the public IP is the one you're trying to use and the private IP is the one `coturn` is listening on.

e.g.:

```
listening-ip: 172.10.10.10
external-ip: 30.30.30.30/172.10.10.10
```

Then try again. Anyway the information you can gather this way can be used to improve the initial question and get more useful answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've edited my post and provided all the necessary screenshots. Please can you help me more, because I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: Now it seems the browser has an issue trying to resolve the domain name. Try using a turn URL with the IP address directly, e.g. `turn:1.2.3.4:3478`, instead of using the domain. Remember that meanwhile you can run a network capture with Wireshark and observe what the browser is trying to do, i.e. you can see the outgoing STUN and TURN requests and the related responses.

Comment: I've already tried that, It doesn't work with turn URL too.